# Osmdroid Cache Location Not Respecting Config

Tags: java, android, maps, osmdroid

I do not want osmdroid to use the external storage location to store cache of tiles. Instead, I want it to use the app's getCacheDir() location. This is the code I have done to achieve this:

```java
        org.osmdroid.config.IConfigurationProvider osmConf = org.osmdroid.config.Configuration.getInstance();
        File basePath = new File(getContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath(), "osmdroid");
        osmConf.setOsmdroidBasePath(basePath);
        File tileCache = new File(osmConf.getOsmdroidBasePath().getAbsolutePath(), "tile");
        osmConf.setOsmdroidTileCache(tileCache);
        osmConf.setUserAgentValue(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        nearbyMap = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.nearby_map);
        nearbyMap.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        nearbyMap.setMultiTouchControls(true);
```

However, I am still getting this error in my app

```
Failed to open database '/storage/emulated/0/osmdroid/tiles/cache.db'.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: Cannot open database '/storage/emulated/0/osmdroid/tiles/cache.db' with flags 0x10000000: Directory /storage/emulated/0/osmdroid/tiles doesn't exist
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:262)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:205)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:512)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:210)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:202)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:1085)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:1065)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:956)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:973)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:965)
    at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.SqlTileWriter.getDb(SqlTileWriter.java:740)
    at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.SqlTileWriter.<init>(SqlTileWriter.java:82)
    at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderBasic.<init>(MapTileProviderBasic.java:89)
    at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderBasic.<init>(MapTileProviderBasic.java:70)
    at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderBasic.<init>(MapTileProviderBasic.java:63)
    at org.osmdroid.views.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:220)
    at org.osmdroid.views.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:193)
    at org.osmdroid.views.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:255)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1010)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
    at xyz.razbot.bussin.NearbyFragment.onCreateView(NearbyFragment.java:296)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7959)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN): Could not open database
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:224)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:205) 
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:512) 
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:210) 
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:202) 
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:1085) 
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:1065) 
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:956) 
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:973) 
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:965) 
    at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.SqlTileWriter.getDb(SqlTileWriter.java:740) 
    at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.SqlTileWriter.<init>(SqlTileWriter.java:82) 
    at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderBasic.<init>(MapTileProviderBasic.java:89) 
    at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderBasic.<init>(MapTileProviderBasic.java:70) 
    at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderBasic.<init>(MapTileProviderBasic.java:63) 
    at org.osmdroid.views.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:220) 
    at org.osmdroid.views.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:193) 
    at org.osmdroid.views.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:255) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1010) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538) 
    at xyz.razbot.bussin.NearbyFragment.onCreateView(NearbyFragment.java:296) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7959) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
2024-03-09 16:28:48.812 12880-12880 OsmDroid                xyz.razbot.bussin                    E  Unable to start the sqlite tile writer. Check external storage availability.
```

full error here https://paste.witherhosting.com/verpeciffe.java, which I don't know how to fix.
Thanks in advance.

I've tried following all the guides online which state to use getCacheDir(), which I have.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.